# How to change the NavigationPage on Scroll

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms

I followed this tutorial (https://xamgirl.com/transparent-navigation-bar-in-xamarin-forms/) to make the navigation bar transparent and it works but I'd like to change the Value="Transparent" let's say to Value="Black" after scrolling down

```
<NavigationPage.BarBackgroundColor>
    <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="Color">
        <On Platform="Android, iOS" Value="Transparent"/>
    </OnPlatform>
</NavigationPage.BarBackgroundColor>
```

I tried to change the color from the .cs file instead of the .xaml but the property doesn't work that way, also tried with binding but if "Value" is empty the application crashes, how can I fix this?

Comment: Do you have a try with  `((NavigationPage)Application.Current.MainPage).BarBackgroundColor = Color.Black;` ?

Comment: What you have been tried Can you show what you did

Comment: @JuniorJiang-MSFT That should work. However, I would suggest null checking and cast with "as" keyword for fail safe.

Comment: Yeah, you're right.I will update in answer.If solved problem, thanks for marking it :)

Answer (score 0):

In Xamrin Forms , if has navigation bar, can set bar background as follow:

```
var navigationPage = Application.Current.MainPage as NavigationPage;
if (null != navigationPage)
{
     navigationPage.BarBackgroundColor = Color.Black;
}
```

Note that Application.Current.MainPage is null when the interface is initialized.

**Updated**:

1. You can determine the horizontal and vertical scroll offset using the `ScrollX` and `ScrollY` properties of your ScrollView. These are bindable, so if you're using MVVM you can map them to properties on your view model. 
   If you're not using MVVM and want to react to changes in `ScrollX` or `ScrollY`, add a listener to the ScrollView's `Scrolled` event.
2. To find the total height or width of the content in the ScrollView, use the `ContentSize` property. The `Content` property will give you the contained `View` itself.

Comment: I see where you are going but I'm still learning xamarin forms and there's something I still don't understand, say If I'm working under "Shell"" there's no navigation page or that's what I understand but there's still a default blue top ToolbarItem can I still access it's properties and set the color to transparent? the idea is that when you scroll down the screen the toolbar changes from transparent to white

Comment: I'm checking this page https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/shell/configuration but still can't figure out how to change the color/transparency at runtime

Comment: @Herb When first entering the page, you can set default color for bar.When scrolling, you can determine the horizontal and vertical scroll offset using the `ScrollX` and `ScrollY` properties of your `ScrollView`. These are bindable, so if you're using MVVM you can map them to properties on your view model. If you're not using MVVM and want to react to changes in `ScrollX` or `ScrollY`, add a listener to the ScrollView's Scrolled event.